# Remove input placeholders on small screen / mobile but add them again when resized to desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label 1</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder 1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label 2</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder 2" class="form-control" />
      </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Label 3</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder 3" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

// Invoke Placeholder plugin to fix the IE9 placeholder issue
$('input, textarea').placeholder();

//Add placeholder on inputs on desktop 
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 767px)", function () {
    $("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-placeholder", this.placeholder);

        $(this).bind("focus", function () {
            this.placeholder = '';
        });
        $(this).bind("blur", function () {
            this.placeholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
        });
    });
});
    // Remove placeholders completely for mobile
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 766px)", function () {
    $("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
        $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
        $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");

        $(this).bind("focus", function () {
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");
        });
        $(this).bind("blur", function () {
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");
        });
    });
});
```

});

Hi,

On my form, I need the placeholders on the input fields to show for desktop only and get removed for mobile. This works fine using the above code except when the user re-sizes their desktop browser window. (i.e. goes from large screen, to small screen and then *back* to large screen again!) In this scenario, the placeholders do not re-appear.

I am using this placeholder plugin to make the placeholders work in older browsers: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

And enquire.js to add/remove the placeholders based on screen size.

Would really appreciate any help you could give.

Cheers,
Maurice.

**Resolved Fiddle - Using Ganesh's answer below**
https://jsfiddle.net/MauriceT/v07ggLpe/23/

Comment: The problem is you are removing the attr itself and later you try and find it by using placeholder but it doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, OK - that makes sense. Is it possible to add the attribute back when the screen resizes? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my code in style tag you can see media query that is 540px, when screen width is 540px or less than that placeholder will hide, when it increases 540px placeholder will appear

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px; 
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
        color: transparent;
    }
    .form-control:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
       color: transparent;
    }
    .form-control::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
       color: transparent;
    }
   .form-control :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
       color: transparent;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: input</h2>
  <p>The form below contains two input elements; one of type text and one of type password:</p>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="ganesh">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a description in your answer about how it actually works between the width changes

Comment: The code is clear. If browser width is below 540px, make placeholders transparent. You can [click here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder) to find out in what browsers you can use "placeholder" pseudo element.

Comment: That look good to me. I just need to delete the code that removes the attribute on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/MauriceT/v07ggLpe/21/

Comment: you asking me to remove the code from your fiddle that removes placeholder right????

Comment: Oh that's OK, Ganesh. I will do that myself! : ) Thanks for your help. I will mark you answer as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

Please Remove `$("input[placeholder]")` to Add `$("input[.form-control]")`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Invoke Placeholder plugin to fix the IE9 placeholder issue
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();

    //Add Remove placeholder on inputs
    $("input[.form-control]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-placeholder", this.placeholder);

        $(this).bind("focus", function () {
            this.placeholder = '';
        });
        $(this).bind("blur", function () {
            this.placeholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
        });
    });

    //Add placeholder on inputs on desktop 
    enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 767px)", function () {
        $(".booking-engine-container input[placeholder]").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("data-placeholder", this.placeholder);

            $(this).bind("focus", function () {
                this.placeholder = '';
            });
            $(this).bind("blur", function () {
                this.placeholder = $(this).attr("data-placeholder");
            });
        });
    });
        // Remove placeholders completely for mobile
    enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 766px)", function () {
        $("input[placeholder]").each(function () {
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
            $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");

            $(this).bind("focus", function () {
                $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
                $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");
            });
            $(this).bind("blur", function () {
                $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("data-placeholder");
                $("input[placeholder]").removeAttr("placeholder");
            });
        });
    });

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/v07ggLpe/19/)

Hope This Should Work....

Comment: Hi Ivin. Thanks but when I try that the placeholder is still visible on mobile. I need it to disappear on small screens and appear on large screens even if change the browser size. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below script to remove place holder on mobile view.

---

```
  <script>
  var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 800px)")
    if (mql.matches){ // if media query matches
    $(':input').removeAttr('placeholder');
  }
  </script>
```